# Prevent copy dialog on iPhone (IOS4) when pressing on jQuery UI Slider

Tags: iphone, jquery-ui, ios4, uislider

On a web page with a jQuery UI Slider, using the iPhone's web browser, pressing and holding a finger on the slider control will pop up (after 2-3 seconds) the phone's built in copy (and more options) dialog. See image of dialog (ignore the rest of the screen content. This is just to illustrate the dialog I'm referring to)

Is there a way to signal to the browser to avoid opening this dialog?

[image]

Comment: Good question, although I don't think that's possible...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the slider to use the javascript swipe event.

For me, I detect iOS browsers and replace all sliders with jscrollpane, it supports finger swiping.

Comment: looks like jscrollpane is designed more for being a scrollbar, not a slider like the jQuery UI one. Although I could probably interchange them in some cases. 
Do you know for a fact, the IOS dialog won't show up with this control?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was thinking of another jQuery UI control.  All of our help files use fixed sized divs that are scrollable, and on the iPad I've never had the copy pane come up on me, unfortunately I don't have an iPad around with me to triple check. :( But maybe you can just dig into jscrollpane and see how they make sure it doesn't happen.